# Filter 2 jsons based on association

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react.
I'm working with the response of 2 api get requests which returned 2 different arrays which contain details of residents and Programs in Json form.

I am trying to filter both arrays which I stored as State so I can display a list of programs with their corresponding resident attendees. How do I go about this?

[This is an example of how a single resident object looks in the resident array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2US5h.jpg)

[This is an example of how a single program object looks in the program array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTofG.jpg)

I have no idea how to go about it

Comment: Please update the question with the neccessary code and examples

Comment: Please post the relavent json and the expected output json